# add button in the body of email ( java )

Tags: java, android-studio

I am creating an app in Android Studio and I would like to add a button into the body of the email by default. So each time the user would like to send an email from my app this button must appear in the body.

This is what I have now:

```
public void open (View view) {
    Intent sendintent = new Intent ( Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendintent.setType("text/plain");
    sendintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email subject");
    sendintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body of Email");
    startActivity(sendintent);

}
```

Thank you for recommendations.

Comment: I would recommend you to start learning about android at first place.

Comment: Yes, I am a beginner, but this is how we all started. I am just trying. Thank you for your replay.

Comment: To start you should change the MIME type to `text/html`; `text/plain` will not be able to display buttons.  Then write the body of the email as an HTML document.

Comment: Thank you very much for help.